# Viewing revisions of a moved example created prior to the move results in 404 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, revision-history, documentation-examples

Moving examples between topics is a great way to reduce clutter and confusion. However, trying to establish what happened on an example *prior to* the move produces errors...

### Steps to reproduce

1. Find an example that was moved at some point in its past. For example, [Introduction to Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/5007/arrow-functions/720/introduction).
2. Click the "edited" link at the end to [view the revision history for that example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/revisions/5007?exampleId=720).
3. Observe that the revision history only goes back as far as the move.

   [image: Revision history post-move]
4. Click the (revisions) link to view [the revision history *prior to* the move](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/revisions/186?exampleId=720).

   [image: partial revision history pre-move]
5. Click "View Topic" on any revision in the pre-move list (that is, any revision *except* for the one that moves the example).
6. Observe that you're looking at a 404 page. Observe also that the topic ID in the resulting URL is the topic that the example was moved *to*, although you clearly indicated that you wished to view a revision prior to the move. 
   [image: the 404 page]

### Expected behavior

Links to revisions of an example prior to it being moved should reference the topic that it was moved from, not the one it was moved to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build, thanks; specifically, the link between steps 5 and 6 will link to the correct topic for the chosen revision.

Comment: Now, trying to rollback to a version prior to the move just results in "An error occurred" (try e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/186/functions/720/introduction?asOf=2016080213353338&rollbackExampleId=720)

Comment: @bwoebi I'll look tomorrow, but literally the only thing I changed was the link

Comment: Wanna report that separately, @bwoebi? Chances are, that bug existed prior to this change, and was just really hard to find because viewing the history didn't work.

Comment: @Shog9 I didn't know whether it was related or not. Looks like it isn't, but Marc already said he'll have a look, shall I still create a bug report nevertheless?

Comment: @bwoebi perhaps the more interesting question here is: should we be able to rollback over moves? I'm thinking we probably shouldn't

Comment: @MarcGravell The point of a rollback is that it also creates a draft you can copy the original source from. I do not necessarily need to be able to actually rollback it, but I may wish to see the source (e.g. copy an old section which had been removed upon moving). And even if you disagree, it should at the very least have a meaningful error message.